# How do I force an app to always start from scratch when it returns from the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, background-process

I'm working on an app that needs to run through a protocol from beginning to end. How do I force the app to always start at the beginning when brought back from the background, regardless of where it was left.
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your goal is to restart the app from scratch at every start up, simply add/change the key `UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend` to `YES` in your info.plist file

Here's the relevant link in the documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: Yes, the other answers are needlessly complicated.  This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use `exit()`. However, that method is only useful for testing/programming purposes. Apple will not accept that being in your code.

Another option would be to create a global session similar to the method used by most social media API's, and in your App Delegate's:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

set the global session to closed. Then just set your protocol logic to restart if the session is closed.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

write your application starting code in `applicationDidBecomeActive` method, because this method calls both time when you start your application first time & also when you cames from background